# Pandas describe() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I cannot understand the meaning of 25% and max of

```
dataframe.describe()
```

I tried to look for it but didn't get any hint whatsoever. I tried on different datasets, 25% isn't always an integer so it cannot be the number of values less than 25% of the max value. What does 25% and max signify?

Comment: I think that [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) could be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If check [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) it is `percentiles`:

> **percentiles** : list-like of numbers, optional
>
> The percentiles to include in the output. All should fall between 0 and 1. The default is [.25, .5, .75], which returns the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
})

#print (df)

print (df.describe())
              B         C         D
count  6.000000  6.000000  6.000000
mean   4.500000  5.500000  2.833333
std    0.547723  2.880972  2.714160
min    4.000000  2.000000  0.000000
25%    4.000000  3.250000  1.000000 <-same output
50%    4.500000  5.500000  2.000000
75%    5.000000  7.750000  4.500000
max    5.000000  9.000000  7.000000

print (df.quantile(.25))
B    4.00
C    3.25
D    1.00
Name: 0.25, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Got it, so 50% will have the median,
25% will have the median of numbers between min and median
and 75% will have the median of numbers between actual median and max term